# Android OpenCV FAST corner detection filtering

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to develop an android app which should analyze the frames from camera and detect corners.

My aim is to detect the current chess board state and provide data to a server.

I've implemened OpenCV in my app and I'm trying to use FAST corner detection.

This is the part of my code where i analyze the current camera frame:

```
 @Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    MatOfKeyPoint points = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    try {
        Mat mat = inputFrame.rgba();
        FeatureDetector fast = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.FAST);
        fast.detect(mat, points);


        Scalar redcolor = new Scalar(255, 0, 0);
        Mat mRgba = mat.clone();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB, 4);

        Features2d.drawKeypoints(mRgba, points, mRgba, redcolor, 1);
        mat.release();
        return mRgba;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return inputFrame.rgba();
    }
}
```

This code works. The problem is that i get too much corners. I'd like to know a way to implement a threshold.

In this [Doc](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_fast/py_fast.html) it talks about a "nonmaxsuppression".

If someone doesn't know an answer but knows where to find android updated documentation, it'll be great!

Thanks!

Comment: You could just sort all the keypoints depending on the [response](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html#a1f163ac418c281042e28895b20514360)

Comment: Could do show me some code? I can't figure out how to get this "response" parameter

Comment: Just added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I know of which you can use to sort the Keypoints:

1. Update the `.xml`/`.yml` file of the detector with a different threshold value. You can find reference on how to do that [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3167/java-how-to-set-parameters-to-orb-featuredetector/?answer=17296#post-id-17296)
2. You can sort the response of the *MatOfKeyPoint* and select the first 100 or 200, as you want. You can use the following to do so in java:

```
// Sort and select 500 best keypoints
List<KeyPoint> listOfKeypoints = matrixOfKeypoints.toList();
Collections.sort(listOfKeypoints, new Comparator<KeyPoint>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(KeyPoint kp1, KeyPoint kp2) {
        // Sort them in descending order, so the best response KPs will come first
        return (int) (kp2.response - kp1.response);
    }
});
List<KeyPoint> listOfBestKeypoints = listOfKeypoints.subList(0, 500);
```

Comment: How do i reconvert listOfKeypoints into "MatOfKeyPoints" to pass to "Features2d.drawKeypoints" parameter?  (second way)

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/utils/Converters.html#vector_vector_KeyPoint_to_Mat(java.util.List, java.util.List)

Answer (score 0):

The FeatureDetector class is deprecated. Now you can use FastFeatureDetector class, which provides a creator with threshold and nonmaxsupression options. Example:

```
public void detectFeatures(Mat img, MatOfKeyPoint fatures) {
    int threshold = 20;
    boolean nonMaxSup = true;
    FastFeatureDetector fast = FastFeatureDetector.create(threshold, nonMaxSup, FastFeatureDetector.TYPE_7_12);
    fast.detect(img, features);
}
```

See documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/index.html)